# Is the empty set always part of the result of an intersection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From very basic set theory we have that:

"The empty set is inevitably an element of every set."

Then, is it correct to assume that the intersection of

$A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $B = \{3, 4, 5\}$ is actually $\{\emptyset, 3\}$, and not just $\{3\}$?

Thank you

Comment: The empty set isn't an element of every set. For instance it isn't an element of itself.

Comment: "The empty set is inevitably an element of every set." is blatantly false. It is a __subset__ of every set, not an element.

Comment: The empty set symbol can be an element of both sets $A$ and $B$ but then it loses its definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is **true** that for all sets $A$, we have $\emptyset \subseteq A$, it is **not true** that for all sets $A$, $\emptyset \in A$.

The intersection of $A,B$ is defined by $A \cap B = \{x | x \in A$ and $x \in B\}$.

What is important here is the difference between being a **subset** and being an **element** of a set. Do you now see why the empty set is not contained in $A\cap B$, with reference to your example?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So for example then, is the empty set an element of the powerset of a set?

Comment: Yes. You can verify this yourself with a trick: if a set $A$ has cardinality $n$, then its powerset always has cardinality $2^n$. Take the set $A = {1}$. Its power set must be two elements, but we only see $1 \in A$. The other element of the power set is going to be the empty set. $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{\{1\},\emptyset\}$

Comment: Thanks! This makes much more sense now

Comment: @borg123 Sure, you're welcome!

Comment: I think in your comment you meant $A = \{1\}$ rather than $A=1$.

Comment: @TrevorWilson Yes, yes I did. Sorry.